# Winforms + MDI children

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi

In WinForms, is there a way to specify initial starting locations of MDI Child windows in a somewhat intelligent manner?

I can apply a manual position, or have it center parent, but neither of these options take much thought into existing windows.

I'd like to know if there is built in way to do a "smart arrangement", or if I need to implement this code myself.

As a side note, are there ways to automate Tiled and Cascaded views as well?

Answer (score 4):

For tiled and cascade you want to use Form.LayoutMdi().

If you want something more sophisticated than that, then you'll need to write some code.